# Ruby special usage of CASE Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, switch-statement, metaprogramming

I've got some piece of code:

```
variable = ...
case variable
when ~:new
  ':new method!'
when ~:lenght
  ':size method!'
end
```

For `o = []` it should go to size case and return ':size method!'
For `o = String` should return ':new method'
And this part I know how to implement(my solution below)
But it should work with any kind of object. And this part I don't know how to implement. I don't know what is wrong in my code and is it correct? My code:

```
module AbstractClass
  def new; false end;
  def size; false end;
end

class Class
  include AbstractClass
end

class Array
  include AbstractClass
  def size; true end;
end

class String
  include AbstractClass
  def new; true end;
end

class Symbol
  include AbstractClass
  alias ~ to_proc
end
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: You can format with indentation or by using the ```{}``` button in the editor.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to achieve. What is the goal of all this?

Comment: This is the exercise and I wrote you the jist of the exercise. There are some automated test which show me that my code is not correct enough. It is said that for Array should return ':size method!', for String ':new method!' and it should work for any kind of method. Thats all what I know

Comment: OK...it's an exercise, i see.
What is the expected output for other objects?

Comment: I've no idea. There is only: `Your code should work with any kind of object.
` but I've written a message to the author with the question 'What is the output for other objects', I suppose it should only work without defining length and new method in each object. But I only suppose and wait for the answer.

Comment: The top-level class to monkey-patch is not `Class` but `Object`. Include your module there and it will affect EVERY instance of any class. (There is also `BasicObject`, but `Object` will do.) You then don't need to include it in `Array` any more, only overriding one of the methods will do.

Answer (score 1):

I know what you did here :) I can give you a hint.

Important thing is to understand how case statements work in Ruby. If you have following code:

```
case variable
when 1
  # do stuff
when "foo"
  # do other stuff
end
```

Ruby is actually calling === method on those values:

```
1 === variable
"foo" === variable
```

Or

```
1.===(variable)
"foo".===(variable)
```

The order is important here. And since those are just methods you can override them for any object to provide some custom behavior related to comparing two objects.

```
def MyClass
  def ===(other)
    # do my own comparison
  end
end
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but how to override those methods for all kind of objects? Override this in `Class` class?

Comment: I believe test cases for this task are more complicated than just those two methods :new and :length. You should write more general solution that will work for any method name

Comment: Yes, there are some automated tests but I don't know how they look like. I've got some piece of code with switch case in body of exercise and thats all. My solution works with objects where I define new and length but  `it should work with any kind of object.`. There should be some sneaky solution I think.